# Exposing IdentityServer4 as both IdentityProvider and ServiceProvider using ComponentSpace

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, identityserver4, saml-2.0, component-space

I am new to ComponentSpace, any experts in ComponentSpace/IdentityServer4 kindly suggest me on the following requirement.

My requirement is to make an IdentityServer4 to be both compatible as an IdentityProvider as well as a ServiceProvider.

Is it possible to meet the above requirement in a single instance (or) do I need to have a separate instance for IdentityProvider and ServiceProvider?

Currently, I had completed POC of running standalone instances of IdP and SP, it is working as expected. Looking forward to make it to run in the same instance.

I had followed the below mentioned documentation.
https://www.componentspace.com/documentation/saml-for-asp-net/ComponentSpace%20SAML%20for%20ASP.NET%20Developer%20Guide.pdf

POC is done in .net Core 2.2 and ComponentSpace 2.5

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done.

I [wrote it up](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/connecting-two-instances-of-identityserver-4-using-the-componentspace-saml-v2-0-for-net-core-stack-2cab05921db5) a while back.

"Essentially what we have is:

CS test client using SAML → idsrv4 running as a IDP and a SP → idsrv4 running as a IDP"